# Upgrading from Win8 to Win8.1 with a Users directory Symlink

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-update, symbolic-link

I run 2 drives in my laptop, ssd and hdd. I created a symlink from `C:\Users` to `D:\Users` to save space on my SSD. During update to windows 8.1, I am prompted with this message:

[image: Error message]

What can I do to make the installer continue and work properly with my setup?

Comment: Try using a Windows 8.1 media the Windows Store method requires certain things to be true.  You should be aware that Microsoft does not officially support moving the user profile and program file folder although they don't stop it

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do to make the installer continue and work properly with my
>   setup?

Move the user partition back to C:. This is the only way to get it working. [MS warned you](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722177%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) not to do this:

> Using ProfilesDirectory to point to a directory that is not the system
>   volume **will block SKU upgrades and upgrades to future versions of
>   Windows**. For example if you use Windows Vista Home Premium with
>   ProfilesDirectory set to D:\, you will not be able to upgrade to
>   Windows Vista Ultimate or to the next version of Windows. The
>   servicing stack does not handle cross-volume transactions, and it
>   blocks upgrades.

This is for Vista, but also applies to Windows 8(.1).